# Overlapping loops inside functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

In code wars, i am training on a project of multiplicative inverse. The goal is, for example -- if "39" is the input the output should be "4" [39 = 3*9 ==> 27 = 2*7 => 14 = 1*4 ==> (4)]. 
i wrote some code which just multiplies the input for only first level(39 ==> 27).

My code until now,

```
function persistence(num) {

var digits = new Array();
digits = num.toString().split("").map(Number);
var res = 1;
for (i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) { res = res * digits[i]; }
return res;
console.log(persistence(digits));

}
```

i am just learning javascript and i am stuck here. I need to loop this process till i get a single digit number.

**CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME?**
Sorry if my question is not clear...

Comment: you just need a while loop to wrap this method

Comment: you can keep your code how it is and literally just make your return statement like this `return num < 10 ? num : persistence(res);`. Your function will still run through but the fraction of a second that it takes will not be missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array methods are your friend. In this case, use `map` and `reduce`:

```js
function multiplyDigits(num) {
  if (num < 10) return num;
  console.log(num);
  const multiplied = String(num)
    .split('')
    .map(Number)
    .reduce((a, n) => a * n, 1);
  return multiplyDigits(multiplied);
}
console.log(multiplyDigits(39));
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from formatting this is very similar to your code. I commented the only two changes:

```js
function persistence(num) {

    var digits = new Array();
    digits = num.toString().split("").map(Number);

    // 1) Added this if statement to return the result
    //   immediately if there is only one digit.
    if ( digits.length === 1 )
        return digits[0];

    var res = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) 
        res = res * digits[i];

    // 2) Changed from `return res;` so that the function you wrote
    //   is called again on the result (if there were more than one digit).
    return persistence(res);

}

console.log(persistence('39'));
```

For a bit shorter of a solution you could use:

```js
function persistence(num) {
    return num < 10 
      ? num
      : persistence( (num+'').split('').reduce( (a,b) => a*b ) );
}

console.log(persistence('39'));
```